# Checkboxes and Delete from Database in PHP While Loop

Tags: php, html, loops, while-loop

I am trying to allow a user to delete any one of these rows by clicking on the delete button for that respective row.  Unfortunately, when they click delete, it deletes all of the rows.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is what the table looks like:

- $metakey | $meta_value | Delete Button

  $metakey | $meta_value | Delete Button

  $metakey | $meta_value | Delete Button

`<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($followerresult)){
        $meta_key=$row["meta_key"];
        $meta_value=$row["meta_value"];`

```
echo "<table><tr> 
    <td>$meta_key</td> 
    <td>$meta_value</td> 
    <td><form ID='deleteform' method='POST'>
    <div id='mySubmit'>
    <input type='submit' name='Delete' value='Delete'>

    </form></td> 
</tr>"; 

 if (isset($_POST['Delete'])) {

                //SQL Delete

               echo $wp_login . " has been removed from access permissions";
```

}

echo "";

```
    ?>
```

Comment: And where is code, that performs delete operation?

Comment: Where is the SQL delete command? That is where the problem resides

Comment: @Vector i dont think that only this is the problem

Comment: Thanks for the help so far everyone. Here is the SQL Delete Function, this is for a wordpress site FYI. I am surprised to hear this is where the issue may be, would not have guessed it.

**$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_value = '$meta_value' AND user_id = '$meta_key'");**

Answer (score 1):

The `$meta_key` and `$meta_value` are not part of the form. You need these to be input fields within the form and then use their values within the `POST` request. Rather than looping through and creating a table, instead loop through and create a full functional form with the correct inputs etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add hidden field to your HTML form.

```
<input type='hidden' name='meta_key' value='$meta_key' />
```

And, you must add WHERE clause to your SQL DELETE statement.